# How to Encrypt Yii2 url

Tags: url, yii2

I want to encrypt Yii2 URL parameters 
Example: http://localhost/school/backend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fview&id=20

20 must be encrypt.

Whats the simplest way in Yii2 to achieve this.

Comment: You mean POST request? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html

Comment: Do you want to hide your internal id (20) from being exposed in the url?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with trying to encrypt part of the URL like that is that the client browser must have the key to use for the encryption.  You can supply that over HTTPS *but* it would mean that anyone could also obtain the key.  Alternatively you could have one key per browsing session, but that will impact performance and may be overkill.

What's the reason for encrypting the id parameter?  If it's just to avoid an insecure direct object reference then you could create a hash for the user based on random data (you'd need a unique hash for each user object).  The hash would make it difficult, but not impossible, to correctly guess another object's hash.  Essentially this is *security by obscurity*.

A better approach is to securely handle viewing other IDs.  For example, it may be that I'm allowed to view my own objects / users but not yours.  To achieve this you should programmatically check the user is authorised to view the object in question.  This does mean writing more code but is a significantly better way of doing things.

Submitting the request by `HTTP POST` would only protect you from a casual user.  A more skilled user (or attacker) would just intercept the `POST` request, modify the value and send it on.